# Docker Compose: Change env variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have writte a `docker-compose.yml` file to create a multi-container app with nodejs and mongodb (so 2 containers), and I want to make some options configurable, as the choice of server address and port.
To do that, I have written what follows in docker-compose.yml to set them as env variables:

```
..
    web:
      environment:
        - PORT=3000
        - ADDRESS=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
..
```

Within the source code of my application, I use `process.env.PORT` and `process.env.ADDRESS` to refer to these variables.

But how can I do if I want to change those values, and for example set `PORT=3001`?
I have to use `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` again and build all the application, included mongodb container?

Comment: Environment variables are runtime instructions, just change them in the `docker-compose.yml` then re-run `docker-compose up`.

Comment: As johnharris85 mentioned, re-running docker-compose up would be enough.
Alternatively to using the environment variables in docker-compose.yml, you could use an environment file: 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> I have to use docker-compose build and docker-compose up again and build all the application, included mongodb container?

Not `build`, just `up`. They are runtime options, not build options. Changing them in the `docker-compose.yml` file and then doing a `docker-compose up` again should recreate the containers with the new environment variables.

Alternatively, you can specify environment variables outside the `docker-compose.yml` file to make for easier changes:

1. One of these methods is to use a `.env` file in the same folder that you execute `docker-compose` form (see https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/ for information on it).
2. Another option is to interpolate environment variables from your shell. You could specify them such as `- PORT=${APP_PORT}` and then `export APP_PORT=3000` on your shell before running `docker-compose`. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/ for more information.

Comment: why docker-compose restart won't reload the .env variables changes?

Comment: Because environment is set at container creation. You will need to recreate the containers using something like `docker-compose up --force-recreate`.